# How do I define a default fallback route in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently upgrading a custom CMS from Laravel 3 to Laravel 4 (this upgrade is important for various reasons).

In the existing version, it has routing set up so that routes can be individually defined--but if someone tries to load a route that is not specifically defined, the system catches it and sends it to a "page processor"--which essentially checks to see if the CMS page/post exists in the database.

The "fallback" or "default" route processing line in Laravel 3 looked like this:

```
Route::get('(.*)', array('uses' => 'myPageLoading@method'));
```

My **problem** is that this syntax is not supported in Laravel 4. How do I do this in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it.

**Laravel 4 Syntax:**

```
Route::any('{all}', array('uses' => 'myPageLoading@method'))->where('all', '.*');
```

Comment: It's important to define that default route after all other routes of your app.