# Refreshing page with React/Laravel application breaks app returns blank page

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-router, laravel-5.4

I have a react application that sits on the Laravel 5.4 framework.
The problem I'm having is that on a page refresh with a URL such as https://app.com/{url}/{slug} breaks the application.

Here is my router component that sits in App.js

```
<Router>
  <div className="App__container container-fluid">
    <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/films" component={FilmsContainer}/>
        <Route path="/films/:slugname" component={FilmPage}/>
      </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Refreshing the page through the browser when the FilmsContainer component is displayed works properly as I have the routes for Laravel configured to return the main layout that holds the React application whenever any web route is hit via this code here.

```
Route::get('{slug}', function() {
    return view('main');
})->where('slug', '(?!api)([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?');
```

However, an issue comes when this Link component is hit,

```
<NavLink className="btn btn-success" to={`/films/${slugName}`}>View Film</NavLink>
```

On the first click, react router successfully renders the component with the correct url, for example: https://www.app.com/films/this-film-name.

However when I refresh the page on this url, the react application breaks,
returning an error in the Javascript console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                          app.js:1
```

When refreshing the page on any url that matches the www.app.com/{route}/{slug}
pattern, the app breaks and nothing is rendered, all I see is a blank white page in the browser.

I've tried using browserHistory and also setting other routes in Laravel web routes file, such as:

```
Route::get('films/{slug}', function() {
    return view('main');
})->where('slug', '(?!api)([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?');
```

to try and match the extra params in the routes and serve the main html file that holds the application.

None of this seems to be working and I'm a little confused, is this a Laravel issue? Do I have react router configured incorrectly? Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you may be calling app.js from a relative path. Like `<script src="app.js"></script>` and so in the films directory it's actually calling `https://www.app.com/films/app.js` and getting a 404, but  Laravel's sending HTML from that `https://www.app.com/films/app.js` URL, hence the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error.

Answer (score 0):

When React Router is changing the browser URL from page to page, that is all done on the client side. You make 1 request to the server for `index.html` (or `index.php`), and the rest is taken care of by React Router. Click the button, change the URL, change the content to display, all within `index.html`.

When you refresh, however, you're making a new request to the server for this weird URL it doesn't know how to handle -- it only knows how to serve up your main `index` file. I'm not too familiar with PHP, but to fix this you just need to tell your server to fall back to your main file. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646606/how-do-i-define-a-default-fallback-route-in-laravel) might guide you in the right direction. When Laravel gets a URL it doesn't know how to handle, it should fall back to your `index` file, which will get served up and then in the browser React Router will handle the routing.

Comment: As i pointed out in the question, I already have this where all routes are returning the index file.